# Why does posix.exec fail to run in an RPM scriplet?

Tags: rpm-spec

I am trying to use posix.exec in the %post Lua scriplet of an RPM spec file, e.g.

```
%post -p <lua> 
posix.exec("/usr/bin/touch /tmp/test.txt")
```

I get the error:

```
Running transaction
  Installing : my-package-1.0.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64                                                              1/1
error: lua script failed: [string "%post(my-package-1.0.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64)"]:1: exec not permitted in this context
```

Why does this error happen? How to run a program in a Lua scriplet via posix.exec? I've tried os.execute and it works for me but I wonder why posix.exec fails while it is provided just for this purpose.

RPM version 4.8.0

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but as I fell over the same thing and this popped up in the google hits: rpm blocks posix.exec if you haven't forked as exec replaces the current process. And exec also does not run shell commands as you seem to expect.

What you need/want is os.execute